# getElementsByClassName(className) returning null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser-addons

What to do if I have to insert some value on a page element of a new tab within a Chrome extension?

I am using:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("quotes").innerHTML = Quotes[x];
```

in `newtab-script.js` page but it is showing this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

My page contains a `div` with a class named `quotes` but when I alert this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("quotes")
```

The result is `null`.

My code is in the form:

```
window.onload = function abc (){ 
  alert(document.getElementById('a'));    
  document.getElementById('a').innerHTML ="ishaan"; 
}
```

I am importing my script file in a html page which overrides Google Chrome's **new tab** page. My script is on the script file.

Comment: "showing some violation error in console" damn hard to just paste the error here

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: and there you have it  Quotes[x] is null

Comment: I have alerted Quotes[x] it is showing the value. I think document.getElementsByClassName("quotes") is null but element with class quotes is present in my html page.

Comment: did you console that as well?

Comment: Yes, i consoled Quotes[x] value is there in it.

Comment: i mean `document.getElementsByClassName("quotes") ` man

Comment: yes it is showing null

Comment: then you don't have elements on the page with a class of quotes or they are not rendered when the code is executing

Comment: That is the problem..Why it is null even though my html page  is having  that class .

Comment: do you execute this code AFTER the page has fully loaded?

Comment: yes i write as this in my script file:-         window.onload = function abc (){
 alert(document.getElementById('a'));
 document.getElementById('a').innerHTML ="ishaan";
}

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple items having same class name

```
var quoteElems=document.getElementsByClassName('quotes')
for(var i=0;i<quoteElems.length;i++){
quoteElems[i].innerHTML=Quotes[x]
}
```

If there is single item having class 'quotes'

`document.getElementsByClassName("quotes")[0].innerHTML = Quotes[x];`

Comment: there is one class only and it' s class is showing as null . Is these any other way to do this in extensions

Comment: Use `alert(quoteElems.length)` to check required element is there or not. It will show the number of element containing  class 'quotes'

Comment: My last snippet will work on single class if exists ,try it.Other wise you have to dynamically create it.

Answer (score 0):

if you use jquery then do

```
 $(function(){
   $('.quotes').html(Quotes[x]);
 });
```

Comment: even then it is not working.It is unable to find element.

Comment: you don't have a element with the class .quotes on the page

Comment: are you using ajax?

Comment: no... i am just importing my script file in html page...which overrides chrome browsers new tab page.... and my script is obviously on the script file